# Change y-axis scaling fontsize in pandas dataframe.plot()

Tags: pandas, formatting

I am changing the font-sizes in my python pandas dataframe plot. The only part that I could not change is the scaling of y-axis values (see the figure below).

Could you please help me with that?

Added:

Here is the simplest code to reproduce my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

start = 10**12
finish = 1.1*10**12
y = np.linspace(start , finish)
pd.DataFrame(y).plot()
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=17)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=17)
```

You will see that this result in the graph similar to above. No change in the scaling of the y-axis.

Ma[image]

Comment: It would be easier to assist if you posted the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Please post it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are just so many features that you can control with the plotting capabilities of pandas, which leverages matplotlib. I found that seaborn is a lot easier to produce pretty charts, and you have a lot more control over the parameters of your plots.

This is not the most elegant solution, but it works; however, it has a seborn dependency:

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)

start = 10**12
finish = 1.1*10**12
y = np.linspace(start , finish)
pd.DataFrame(y).plot()
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=17)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=17)
```

I use Jupyter Notebook an that's why I use **%pylab inline**. The key element here is the use of

> **font_scale=1.5**

Which you can set to whatver you want that produces your desired result. This is what I get:
[image: controlling the font size in a pandas df plot]